# Fuzzy Match and replace strings in dataframe using custom dictionnary

Tags: r, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-comparison

I have this dataframe with similars (strings with small syntax differences)

```
 place1 <- c("pondichery ", "Pondichery", "Pondichéry", "Port-Louis", "Port Louis  ")
 place2 <- c("Lorent", "Pondichery", " Lorient", "port-louis", "Port Louis")
 place3 <- c("Loirent", "Pondchéry", "Brest", "Port Louis", "Nantes")

 places2clean <- data.frame(place1, place2, place3)
```

Here is my custom dictionnary

```
  dictionnary <- c("Pondichéry", "Lorient", "Port-Louis", "Nantes", "Brest")

  dictionnary <- data.frame(dictionnary)
```

I want to match and replace all strings based on a custom dictionnary.

Expecteds results :

```
    place1     place2     place3
 Pondichéry     Lorient    Lorient
 Pondichéry Pondichéry Pondichéry
 Pondichéry    Lorient      Brest
 Port-Louis Port-Louis Port Louis
 Port-Louis   Port-Louis     Nantes
```

How can I use stringdistance for matching and replacing over all the dataframe?

Comment: The [fuzzyjoin](https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin) package probably has the functionality you're after.

Comment: Any answer with fuzzyjoin package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following first computes matrices of distances between each column and the dictionary and then gets the strings that have a smaller distance.

```
library(stringdist)

places2clean[] <- lapply(places2clean, trimws)

d <- lapply(places2clean, function(x) {
  sapply(dictionnary$dictionnary, function(y) stringdist(x, y))
})
res <- sapply(d, function(x){
  inx <- apply(x, 1, which.min)
  dictionnary$dictionnary[inx]
})

as.data.frame(res)
#      place1     place2     place3
#1 Pondichéry    Lorient    Lorient
#2 Pondichéry Pondichéry Pondichéry
#3 Pondichéry    Lorient      Brest
#4 Port-Louis Port-Louis Port-Louis
#5 Port-Louis Port-Louis     Nantes
```

Answer (score 3):

Either the base R function `adist` or the `stringdist::amatch` function would be of use here. There's no reason to make your dictionary into a `data.frame`, so I haven't here.

If you wanted to experiment, you could use different methods for the stringdist package, though the default works fine here. Note for both functions, the best match is chosen, but if there is no close match (as defined by the maxDist parameter), then NA is returned.

```
library(stringdist)
# Using stringdist package
clean_places <- function(places, dictionary, maxDist = 5) {
  dictionary[amatch(places, dictionary, maxDist = maxDist)]
}

# Using base R
clean_places2 <- function(places, dictionary, maxDist = 5) {
  sm <- adist(places, dictionary)
  sm[sm > maxDist] <- NA
  dictionary[apply(sm, 1, which.min)]
}

dictionary <- c("Pondichéry", "Lorient", "Port-Louis", "Nantes", "Brest")
place1 <- c("pondichery ", "Pondichery", "Pondichéry", "Port-Louis", "Port Louis  ")
place2 <- c("Lorent", "Pondichery", " Lorient", "port-louis", "Port Louis")
place3 <- c("Loirent", "Pondchéry", "Brest", "Port Louis", "Nantes")

clean_places(place1, dictionary)
# [1] "Pondichéry" "Pondichéry" "Pondichéry" "Port-Louis" "Port-Louis"
clean_places(place2, dictionary)
# [1] "Lorient"    "Pondichéry" "Lorient"    "Port-Louis" "Port-Louis"
clean_places(place3, dictionary)
# [1] "Lorient"    "Pondichéry" "Brest"      "Port-Louis" "Nantes"    

clean_places2(place1, dictionary)
# [1] "Pondichéry" "Pondichéry" "Pondichéry" "Port-Louis" "Port-Louis"
clean_places2(place2, dictionary)
# [1] "Lorient"    "Pondichéry" "Lorient"    "Port-Louis" "Port-Louis"
clean_places2(place3, dictionary)
# [1] "Lorient"    "Pondichéry" "Brest"      "Port-Louis" "Nantes"
```